# Socket Error: 111 [.connect((host, port))]

Tags: python, sockets

I am doing a course and it is teaching me socket right now but this code they are showing is not working for me?

```
import socket


def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "localhost"
    port = 5000

    s.connect((host, port))
    print("It works!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_connection.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "create_connection.py", line 9, in main
    s.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

EDIT:

On this video there is nothing listening but there is no error?

Comment: On the video there is no server waiting but it still works.

Comment: They may not be showing it to you.

Comment: Check please - https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect request failed with connection refused.
You need a TCP server which is listening on 5000 port.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a server waiting for connection in port 5000, only then it will work. Otherwise this error is expected